# Rotation of rigid body after inelastic collision with smaller mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, energy-conservation, rotational-dynamics

> A slender rod of length $l$, with no mass, is able to rotate around an axis through its center, with no friction. There are two points of mass $M$ and negligible radius attached to each end of the rod. The rod is initially horizontal and is not moving.
>
> A blob of putty of mass $m$ falls due to gravity from height $h$ above one of the balls and sticks to it. At what angle $\phi$ above the horizontal does the rod come to rest momentarily as it oscillates?

So, how do I approach this problem? I get that the kinetic energy of the ball goes into making the rod move, but what then? The balls at the ends of the rod are now of uneven mass, so the heavier one exerts a force that produces a torque and continues the rotation and I just can't visualize how can that system can ever come to a standstill. How should I approach this?

Comment: You should post the question exactly as it was worded, because as stated now (v1), it makes no sense.

Comment: I did rephrase the only thing I find ambiguous, this is exactly how it is worded (minus the translation to English).

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. What's the initial position of the rod? Is gravity involved? How fast does the ball "drop"? Why would it stop rotating? It sounds like you only heard half the question.

Comment: Gravity IS involved, the initial position of the rod is horizontal, and not rotating, I think it would stop rotating because once it gets past 180° the torque of gravity on the heavier end should stop the rotation.

Comment: What's to stop it from rotating?  It will rotate forever.

Comment: The wording is still ambiguous.  I presume that the rotation axis is at the center of the rod, perpendicular to the rod, and that the axis of rotation is fixed.   Also there is a mass at either end of the rod, not two masses attached  to one end.  The two masses are identical.  I assume that "which is not moving" means that initially the rod is stationary.  I also assume that the rod is initially horizontal.  What happens in the collision? Does the first bounce straight up? From what height was it dropped? Please clarify these details in and edit to the question (not in the comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have understood your professor's intentions and have taken the liberty of editing your question accordingly.

The collision between the blob and one ball is inelastic, so we cannot use Conservation of Energy. However, as your professor suggests, we can use Conservation of Angular Momentum :

The initial angular momentum is $\frac12mvl$ where $v$ is the velocity which the blob acquires after falling through height $h$. Suppose the angular velocity of the rod immediately after this collision is $\omega$. The angular momentum is then $J\omega=mvl$ where $J$ is the moment of inertia of the rod-and-masses system, including the blob of putty.

After the collision the rod will swing through $180^\circ$ and then a bit further, until the increase in the PE of the system equals the loss of the KE $\frac12 J\omega^2$ which it had immediately after the collision with the blob. (This is where conservation of energy comes in.) It will then swing backwards in the opposite direction, and continue swinging like a rigid pendulum.

Except for the blob, the rod-and-two-masses is perfectly balanced, so its PE does not vary as it turns. We only need to consider the change in the PE of the blob after the collision.

We must assume that the rod-and-mass system does not gain so much momentum that the heavier ball (with the blob) swings past the vertical and continue rotating indefinitely. In the problem your professor set, a value of $h$ would have been used which avoids this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the question says that rod stops rotating, then there must be friction somewhere that takes away kinetic energy of rotation. Final equilibrium position must be that in which rod is vertical with heavier mass at bottom (assuming friction is low enough that it can be overcome by the torque produced by imbalance of weights at rod ends).

Comment: Yes I thought so too, but apparently not. The professor hinted I should use conservation of angular momentum during the impact first, and then conservation of mechanical energy in the rod second. I still don't have the slightest idea how.

Comment: Either you have misunderstood his question (looks more likely to me, sorry) or he is wrong. In any case discuss it with him.